# Laravel Migration Local vs Production

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So, the application was running just fine on production and local. Then, locally, I made a couple changes to the DB such as adding a column and changing the attributes of a column. When I went to migrate locally, I got an error, so I ended up deleting that migration file, rolling back the whole table, and creating a fresh migration with everything set up as I want it. Migrated that locally and it's working.

Now, I pushed these changes to github and they're automatically pulled to Laravel Forge and off to the production server. I get an error saying "table already exists". So, the github repository has a new migration for that one table that is already running on my production server.

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve this issue without upsetting the records currently in the production DB table AND making sure there's a migration in place in case I need to drop the table.

Thanks!

Comment: This is one of those instances where you truly realise the importance of a staging/production-shadow server :)

Comment: What's "production-shadow"?

Comment: It's where you "stage" a deployment first before deploying to live server to mitigate some of the problems of directly deploying changes to a live server. Such as this. Specially where there are multiple devs working on a single project, and there are migration scripts involved it really comes in handy.

Comment: Ok, yeah I do that now, however not as successfully due to this. Local environment, staging environment, and production environment.

Comment: Did the below solve your problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add new columns or change anything on a database that is production.

You'll need to create a new migration adding those rows to the database. It's not as easy as just changing your existing migration.

The reason you're getting "table already exists" on production is because the migration has already run.

If for example you had a user's table already migrated and decided you wanted to add a nickname to the existing table.

You would create a new migration `php artisan make:migration alter_users_table_add_nickname`

and then inside this migration insted of using `Schema::create` it would make use of `Schema::table`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('nickname');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropColumn('nickname');

    });
}
```

You can read more here on [Creating Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-columns)

Comment: Right, I've got that covered. However, in this specific case, I should have asked, how to reconcile the new migration file in my repository and the file on the server. Maybe it's as simple as syncing the production branch with my local branch so those files are the same how.

Comment: Well, a quick fix would be to export the content of your production DB not the structure. Delete the tables and run deploy on forge to rerun the migrations with your edited migration and then import the data back in. I would however suggest checking back out the commit where you had the original migration and follow the steps above.

Comment: Ok, per your last sentence, I need to sync production back to local so those migrations are the same again. I'll do that and follow up with marking your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Let me know how you go.

Comment: I ended up exporting the table records (using MySQL Workbench), dropping the table, then running the migration again and reloading the records back in. Super easy. Thanks!